# Getting a build err when I do "dotnet run"

Tags: visual-studio-2019, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.0

I am having problems Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 5.0.0-rc2 as explained in this post "https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1185".

So I added added the daily build of version 5.0.0-rc3 witch is 5.0.0-rc3-preview-0941 currently from "https://www.myget.org/feed/domaindrivendev/package/nuget/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore". I did this by adding the myget source to VS2019.

Here is a link to image show how I have VS setup: [image]

After adding the rc3 I am getting the below build error. I am not sure if this is a problem with Swashbuckle or some other problem.

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3073 The command "dotnet "C:\Users\CTGCntrols\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.apidescription.server\0.3.0-preview7.19365.7\build\/../tools/dotnet-getdocument.dll" --assembly "C:\Users\CTGCntrols\Source\Repos\FlameMetals\API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\API.dll" --file-list "obj\API.OpenApiFiles.cache" --framework ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0" --output "obj" --project "API" --assets-file "C:\Users\CTGCntrols\Source\Repos\FlameMetals\API\obj\project.assets.json" --platform "x64" " exited with code 7.   API C:\Users\CTGCntrols\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.apidescription.server\0.3.0-preview7.19365.7\build\Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server.targets  41  

<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc3-preview-0931" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="5.0.0-rc8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0-rc3-preview-0931" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.0.0-rc3-preview-0931" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0-rc3-preview-0931" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Whoever is facing this error, please follow below steps

1. copy the text starting from "dotnet" till the end of "--platform". (showing in your error list. exited with code not required while copying)
2. Open a command prompt and paste the text.
3. hit enter, now you can see your error. fix the same and build your project.

**sample from the question**

"dotnet "C:\Users\CTGCntrols.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.apidescription.server\0.3.0-preview7.19365.7\build/../tools/dotnet-getdocument.dll" --assembly "C:\Users\CTGCntrols\Source\Repos\FlameMetals\API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\API.dll" --file-list "obj\API.OpenApiFiles.cache" --framework ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0" --output "obj" --project "API" --assets-file "C:\Users\CTGCntrols\Source\Repos\FlameMetals\API\obj\project.assets.json" --platform "x64"

---

My issue was, same method/path given for two methods. ([Route("drivers/{id}")])

Comment: This worked for us.  Turned out we didn't have the proper .NET framework installed.

Answer (score 3):

The actual exception is swallowed. The generation of the documentation fails because:

> System.NotSupportedException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - XXX.Controllers.ControllerYYY.ActionZZZ. Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger 2.0

It's a purely swagger-related error. I saw that error before in the `Error List` window in Visual Studio 2017 but I guess they still gearing up VS 2019 and .NET Core...

You can see the actual exception by executing the said command manually. Just open a Command Prompt window and paste the text:

`dotnet "C:\Users\CTGCntrols.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.apidescription.server\0.3.0-preview7.19365.7\build/../tools/dotnet-getdocument.dll" --assembly "C:\Users\CTGCntrols\Source\Repos\FlameMetals\API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\API.dll" --file-list "obj\API.OpenApiFiles.cache" --framework ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0" --output "obj" --project "API" --assets-file "C:\Users\CTGCntrols\Source\Repos\FlameMetals\API\obj\project.assets.json" --platform "x64"`

### UPDATE

Actually, ANY exception during the XML documentation generation might cause the build error. E.g., if there is a typo in the route path and the route template is rendered invalid, you will get the same build error.

The described behavior is experienced with .NET Core 3.0 and Visual Studio 2019 PREVIEW Version .16.4.0. Preview 1.0

---

Answer (score 0):

I found for some reason the file "API.OpenApiFiles.cache" in the project's obj folder was not created. I created one manually.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is swagger related 
upgrade to version 5.0.0-rc5 should solve the problem
replace the package reference with the new version

`<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0-rc5" />`

and here is the nuget link if you need it
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger/5.0.0-rc5

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is installing Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.cli globally, then issue is resolved:

```
dotnet tool install --global Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.cli --version 5.3.1
```